# How to store build artefacts in TFS?

Tags: tfs, build

I have a TFS server, and an older build system that produces a pile of executables, installers, WinCE images, etc.

Is there an easy way to upload build artefacts to somewhere (where?) in TFS from batch files? Or is this the wrong technology?

Comment: Binaries shouldn't be put into source control. Your CI system should keep track of what artifacts are created and where they go.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the TF Build server and set the Build Definition to "store on server". This will upload all build output to the server in an unversioned repository that while seperate from version Control is also in the database.

You can do this manually through the TFS API but it would not be registered build output associated with a build and version.